# Cassandra ColumnFamily Configuration for hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cassandra

I am using Cassandra database to insert values from a Ruby webservice. I want to insert values from a hash like this:

```
:partners_daily    => [partner_id,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month,time.day].join("_"),
:partners_monthly  => [partner_id,activity_type,success_string,time.year,time.month].join("_"),
:partners_alltime  => [partner_id,activity_type,success_string].join("_")
```

Where partners_daily, partners_monthly, partners_alltime are different columnfamilies in a keyspace.
I want to know what configuration I should chose for these column families to make it compatible to insert hash values in key value pair ?

For now I am using this

```
create column family partners_daily with key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type' and comparator = 'UTF8Type' and default_validation_class = 'CounterColumnType';
```

But its failing to insert values and giving `error:null` pop ups when I select `show 1000 rows` in cassandra-gui.

How should I configure it to make it work?